# Camera changes view when controller connected

Tags: xna, camera, xbox-controller

I have a weird situation. I have a model set to 0 for X,Y and Z. My camera's position is set to:

- 0 (X-value, but updates when the model moves around)
- the model's height + 20f (about the same level as the model's
  shoulders)
- `25f` (behind the model)

Without the controller plugged in, everything looks fine as I want it. But as soon as I plug the controller in, the camera aims to the sky! But when I unplug the controller, the camera is back to what it should be.

Does anyone have any insight as to what may cause this from plugging a controller in?

Comment: You're going to have to show us some of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon your observation that the camera changes when you plug in a controller, your program apparently has some code which notices that a controller is connected, and changes the camera behaviour in that situation.

If you remove or disable that code, then connecting a controller should stop causing problems.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It was in my controller class. I had a value set 200f still. After setting it to 20f, the camera went back to normal again with the controller plugged in.

Comment: I think answers like this are like when you're playing "Guess Who" and you guess right on the first guess.

Comment: @Byte56 You're just jealous of my amazing psychic powers of debugging-code-without-having-access-to-the-code.  xD

Comment: @TrevorPowell Exactly.